# mysql select top N records conditionally

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following  table :

```
+------+------+-----+---------+------------+
| no   | code |eot  |group_id | compulsary |
+------+------+-----+---------+------------+
| 1005 | 101  |  51 |     1   |          1 | 
| 1005 | 102  |  67 |     1   |          1 | 
| 1005 | 121  |  65 |     1   |          1 |
| 1005 | 231  |  82 |     2   |          0 |
| 1005 | 232  |  56 |     2   |          0 |
| 1005 | 233  |  45 |     2   |          1 |
| 1005 | 313  |  80 |     3   |          0 |
| 1005 | 443  |  50 |     4   |          0 |     

|------+------+-----+---------+------------+
```

now what i want is :

1.) return all records where `group_id=1`,

2.) return the best two from group_id=2(however if `compulsary=1` then include that row and the best from the remaining `group_id=2`),

3.)return 1 row each from `group_id=3` and `group_id=4` and if `compulsary=1` then   return that row

the final result should have only seven rows:

```
+------+------+-----+---------+------------+
| no   | code |eot  |group_id | compulsary |
+------+------+-----+---------+------------+
| 1005 | 101  |  51 |     1   |          1 | 
| 1005 | 102  |  67 |     1   |          1 | 
| 1005 | 121  |  65 |     1   |          1 |
| 1005 | 231  |  82 |     2   |          0 |
| 1005 | 233  |  45 |     2   |          1 |
| 1005 | 313  |  80 |     3   |          0 |
| 1005 | 443  |  50 |     4   |          0 |     

|------+------+-----+---------+------------+
```

with the `compulsary=1` rows inluded like above;

so far I have this query though I don't know how to check for the `compulsary` to get what I want:

```
select rg.* 
from 
(
  select * 
  from 
  (
    select 
      rgrade.*,
      @rn := if(@gr=group_id,if(@gr:=group_id,@rn+1,@rn+1),if(@gr:=group_id,1,1)) as rn 
    from rgrade 
    cross join (select @rn:=0,@gr:=0) as vars 
    where admission_no=1005
  ) v 
  where (group_id=1) 
     or (group_id=2 and if(compulsary=1,rn<=1,rn<=2)) 
     or (group_id in (3,4) and rn=1)
) rg  
order by group_id;
```

the query returns the seven rows as expected but does not check for `compulsary` in `group_id=2`.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: don't use `select` in `select` in `select`, it's not optimally and not like the Inception film)

Comment: If more rows are 'group_1' then there will be more rows in your result set, right?

Comment: @Strawberry, best here means the max value

Comment: and there will not be more group_1 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mimic standard SQL's

```
row_number() over (partition by group_id 
                   order by case when compulsary = 1 then 1 else 0 end desc, eot desc)
```

with MySQL means. And I see the partitioning by `group_id` in your query, but I don't see any ORDER BY to get the best records first.

Here is my attempt on it. There may be mistakes; I'm no MySQL guy.

```
select
  no, code, eot, group_id, compulsary
from
(
  select 
    no, 
    code,
    eot,
    compulsary,
    @row_number := 
      case when group_id = @last_group_id then @row_number + 1 else 1 end as row_number,
    @last_group_id := group_id as group_id
  from rgrade
  cross join 
  (
    select 
      @row_number := 0, 
      @last_group_id := -1
  ) as vars
  where admission_no = 1005
  order by group_id, (compulsary = 1) desc, eot desc
) ranked
where (group_id = 1)
   or (group_id = 2 and row_number <= 2)
   or (group_id = 3 and row_number = 1)
   or (group_id = 4 and row_number = 1)
order by group_id, code;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are describing several queries here, the result of which you want combined: All `group_id = 1`, the two best `group_id = 2`, the best of `group_id = 3`, and the best of `group_id = 4`. So write these queries and combine them with `UNION ALL`. With "best" defined as `compulsary = 1` preferred, then highest eot, you get:

```
(select * from mytable where group_id = 1)
union all
(select * from mytable where group_id = 2 order by compulsary = 1 desc, eot desc limit 2)
union all
(select * from mytable where group_id = 3 order by compulsary = 1 desc, eot desc limit 1)
union all
(select * from mytable where group_id = 4 order by compulsary = 1 desc, eot desc limit 1)
order by group_id, no, code
;
```

Comment: @Strawberry: Thanks for editing. You are right, ordering by `(compulsary = 1)` makes sure we'd handle `compulsary > 1` correctly. If `compulsary` can only be 0 or 1 as in the example, my `order by compulsary desc` would suffice, however.

Comment: @Strawberry.. another issue here is am querying a temporary table so i get the error cannot reopen table

Comment: In MySQL temporary tables cannot be used more than once in a query, which makes them rather useless for many operations. So either use a real table (that you can delete when you are done with it) or use a view instead (though data access can be time consuming then).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You're right - somehow I had it my mind that compulsary [sic] could be a value other than 1 or 0 - but that seems not to be the case.